# How to access record variables in a java transaformer

Tags: java, mule, transformer-model

I'm converting a flow from straight single thread, to use a batch processor. So, I'm converting most of the flow variables to recordVars. Some questions i can't find in the docs:

- How do i access a record var in a java transformer? I'm used to message.getInvocationProperty for flow vars
- What happens when i change a flow var - can other threads in the batch see the changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access recordVars form Java or Groovy component using the following:

```
import com.mulesoft.module.batch.record.BatchUtils;
...
BatchUtils.getRecord(message).getVariable('myVar');
```

Comment: To add to that, you can use `BatchUtils.getRecord(message).addVariable('myVar', myVal)` and BatchUtils.getRecord(message).removeVariable('myVar')